# Google Identity Migration with Direct Usage of GAPI.Client

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, google-sso

We got a message to migrate to the new Google Identity Service.

We do a direct usage of GAPI.Client for authentication and not the Javascript Platform library.

Does anyone know if the deprecation would affect us?

According to [this blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html), it doesn't seem to be affected but we are getting the emails from Google asking us to migrate.

Comment: As per my understanding. It's just the `Javascript` Library that's affected and other back-end client libraries need not to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. Unfortunately, the deprecation definitely impacts you if you are using the `gapi` library on your side (see [this announcement from Google](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html)).

You will need to reproduce what you achieve with `gapi` (in particular, user authentication and session management) with the new Google Identity Services and/or Server side OAuth.

[This documentation shows how individual Gapi functions can be reproduced using GIS Auth and/or a Server side solution.](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis)